# Axios call to set authorisation header not working properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I have a React Native app using Axios.
Im trying to authenticate the user and then set the authorization header from the response but im getting a weird order of execution.
The setClientToken is not being called before the code after it to do a get request is to be called. ie this is what i get logged:

```
Loggin in....
Authenticating...
Getting Recipes...
Auth... undefined
Done.
... [Error: Request failed with status code 401] //getRecipes call
Setting token
```

So you see setting token is done last and that means every axios after that will work but not the recipe.js call.

```
//app.js
async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Loggin in....");
    await LogIn(getUser().username, getUser().password);
    console.log("Done.");
 }
render () {
//Recipe component rendered.
}
//recipesApi.js
export function getRecipes(category, offset, count) {
   console.log("Getting Recipes...");
   const url = `search?category=${category}&currentPage=${offset}&pageSize=${count}`;
   console.log("Auth...", APIKit.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"]);
   return APIKit.get(getUrl(url));
}

//user.js
import APIKit, { setClientToken } from "./apiKit";

export default async function LogIn(email, password) {
   console.log("Authenticating...");
   APIKit.post("/users/authenticate", {
    username: email,
    password: password,
   })
    .then((token) => setClientToken(token))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}

//APIKit.js
import axios from "axios";

// Create axios client, pre-configured with baseURL
let APIKit = axios.create({
 baseURL: "http://192.168.1.4:4000/api",
 timeout: 10000,
 });

 APIKit.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response.data;
 });
 
export const setClientToken = (token) => {
  console.log("Setting token...", token.token);
  APIKit.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
       config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token.token}`;
     return config;
  }, null, { synchronous: true }
 );
};
```

Comment: Have you checked that the api call working in postman ?

Comment: I can see before the setting token the getting recipes called... can you check for the your api call flow

Comment: also, your token hasn't been set up before calling the get recipe api call.

Comment: Its not those things, still not working.

Comment: Sorry i can't get you point can you please tell me again

Comment: The "then" in the login function is not being called before "Getting recipes". Why not?

Comment: Can you log the user token like this way => .then((token) => console.log(token))

Comment: What the value you are getting in the log ?

Comment: Yes i get the token object in the log. Object {
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOnsiaWQiOjEsImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6Ik1hbGNvbG0iLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6IlNtaXRoIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJtYWxjb2xtczY1QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInJvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImhhc2giOiIkMmEkMTAkZkNHNWcwMTJZRGJQNXMuQTM1L01kZTRuRFZtOC5ydnlsMm1Pa2RMV2ZKaFpMckdBajNhak8iLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDIxLTA2LTE5VDA2OjAyOjMzLjAwMFoiLCJ1cGRhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDIxLTA2LTE5VDA2OjAyOjMzLjAwMFoifSwiaWF0IjoxNjI1NjU4NDM5LCJleHAiOjE2MjYyNjMyMzl9.ZOue3LDEFPLppvxkC_fC9AJQm_DV0ovm4Jg4-EecxGw",
} Why wouldnt it call setClientToken and pass  the token?

Comment: from where you are calling the getRecipes method ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234617/discussion-between-user8717499-and-jignesh-mayani).